# Get-PartitionSupportedSize is failing with error

Tags: powershell, partition

Here is the command which I am using:

```
for $disk in Get-Disk
    $driveLetter = (Get-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number | where {$_.DriveLetter}).DriveLetter
    $partitionNum = (Get-Partition -DriveLetter $driveLetter).PartitionNumber
    $allowedSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber $disk.Number -PartitionNumber $partitionNum).SizeMax
    Write-verbose "Total Partition Size allowed: $allowedSize"
```

Here is the stack:

```
Get-PartitionSupportedSize : Failed
Activity ID: {a5e65922-521b-46c4-aac8-047ea73a3790}
At C:\extendPartition.ps1:30 char:25
+ ... owedSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber $disk.Number -Part ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_Partition) [Get-PartitionSupportedSize], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4,Get-PartitionSupportedSize
```

Not able to find any good links for the same, so any leads are appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for missing out few things. So I have modified my code to show what I was trying. As you can see, I am trying to just print the allowedSize. 
Next the function Get-PartitionSupportedSize is failing on **Windows 10 Virtual Machine**.

Comment: First, your for loop is formatted incorrectly, your going to have errors if you have multiple partitions on the same drive, they are all going to be in bytes, How are you going to match the get-disk friendly name with the sizemax?

If you want to work it out and go from there, I can appreciate that. If you want the answer, just ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Set-Service -Name defragsvc -StartupType Manual`

Fix the issue.

Comment: I don't know why, but this was the issue on my side

Answer (score 2):

Well since someone gave you an answer to fix your code, I thought I should give you the works, minus the partition types. Was having a bit of a hard time trying to link the partition types to the file size from the `get-PartitionSupportedSize`.

## Input

```
$AllowedSize = @()

Foreach($Disk in (Get-Disk)){
    $Output = (get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber $disk.Number)
    If($Output.count -gt 1){
        Foreach($HDD in $Output){
            $HDD.SizeMax = ([math]::round($HDD.sizemax/1GB, 2));$HDD.SizeMin = ([math]::round($HDD.sizemin/1GB, 2))
            $Output | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FriendlyName -NotePropertyValue $disk.FriendlyName -Force
        }
    } Else {
        $Output.SizeMax = ([math]::round($Output.sizemax/1GB, 2));$Output.SizeMin = ([math]::round($Output.sizemin/1GB, 2))
        $Output | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FriendlyName -NotePropertyValue $disk.FriendlyName -Force
    }
    $AllowedSize += $Output
}
$AllowedSize
```

## Output

```
SizeMin SizeMax FriendlyName             
------- ------- ------------             
    0.1     0.1 NVMe Samsung SSD 960     
   0.44    0.44 NVMe Samsung SSD 960     
   0.02    0.02 NVMe Samsung SSD 960     
 461.26  465.21 NVMe Samsung SSD 960     
   3.05  111.79 Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB
   0.12    0.12 ST2000DM006-2DM164       
1169.37 1662.89 ST2000DM006-2DM164       
 130.03     200 ST2000DM006-2DM164
```

Comment: on Virtual Machine , you code gives me following output :SizeMin SizeMax FriendlyName
------- ------- ------------
      0       0 VMware Virtual disk
      0       0 VMware Virtual disk

Answer (score -1):

Few small things
This worked for me

```
$PartitionNum=3 #or whatever You need 
  foreach ($disk in Get-Disk)
        {
            $allowedSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber $disk.Number -PartitionNumber $partitionNum).SizeMax
        }
```

However:

- `$allowedSize` will be overwritten with each turn of the loop
- `$partitionNum` is defined once. if You want to loop through all partitions you might want to do something like
  `Get-Partition |select -Property PartitionNumber,  DriveLetter, type  ,@{n='sizemax';e={($_|Get-PartitionSupportedSize).sizemax}}, @{n='sizemin';e={($_|Get-PartitionSupportedSize).sizemin}}`